# Higher inductive type: what for?

Tags: homotopy-theory, formal-proofs, type-theory, higher-category-theory, homotopy-type-theory

The typical example of higher inductive type (HIT) is the circle $S^1$ that is nicely described [here](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2011/04/24/higher-inductive-types-a-tour-of-the-menagerie/). I understand HITs are convenient if you want to do homotopy theory within type theory. But what does it bring the computer scientist? Are there interesting data structures that could not be defined without an HIT?

Comment: Just to amend Mike's answer, Thorsten Altenkirch has [some applications](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/talks/lyon14.pdf) of HITs to the theory of containers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question.  To start with I should be clear that I think HITs are probably much *more* interesting to a homotopy theorist than to a computer scientist.  However, it seems that they are not completely devoid of interest to a computer scientist either.

One general class of applications is to constructing true quotients, where you have a data structure in which the same "real object" has multiple representations; by representing it as a HIT you can add actual equalities between the two representations so that any function defined on this data structure must necessarily respect that equality (be "representation-independent").

Additionally, here are some posts from the homotopy type theory blog on topics that might be of interest to computer scientists:

- [Abstract types with isomorphic types](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2012/11/12/abstract-types-with-isomorphic-types/)
- [Higher lenses](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2014/04/29/higher-lenses/)
- [Homotopical patch theory](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2014/09/01/homotopical-patch-theory/)
- [HoTTSQL](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2016/09/26/hottsql-proving-query-rewrites-with-univalent-sql-semantics/)

Comment: What do you mean by "true" quotient? In which way is it different from setoids (as in, e.g., Coq.Lists.SetoidList)?

Comment: A setoid is a type equipped with an equivalence relation.  The "actual" identity type of the underlying type is still there and doesn't coincide with the equivalence relation.  In particular that means you can define functions on it that distinguish points that are related by the equivalence relation.  By contrast, in a true quotient, the equivalence relation gets identified with the identity type, and thus it becomes impossible to distinguish points that it identifies.

Comment: Assuming a type `A` and an equivalence relation `R : A -> A -> Prop`, how would you define the HIT `A/R` that is the true quotient of `A` by `R`?

Comment: A constructor `[-] : A -> A/R`, a constructor `forall (x y : A), R x y -> [x] = [y]`, and probably a 0-truncation constructor `forall (x y : A/R) (p q : x = y), p = q`.  See section 6.10 in the HoTT Book.

Comment: Is it implemented somewhere? I surely would have use for a version of Coq allowing for defining true quotients! Is there  plan to add HITs to Coq?

Comment: The HoTT/Coq library https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT uses a "private inductive types" hack to pseudo-implement HITs, including quotients (file `theories/HIT/quotient.v`).  I don't think there are plans to implement HITs natively in Coq, but some other proof assistants such as Lean http://leanprover.github.io/ and Cubical Agda https://github.com/agda/cubical do include them.